# Math Self Learning

Tags: self-learning

Is it possible to learn math all on your own and reach the same level as a person who has gone through a four years undergrad math specialist study in a university?

Comment: The answers are very motivating for those who wish to learn the subject, especially high school students.  I'm sad to see the four close votes during review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is `Yes` for sure.

However, you need a plan and you need to be honest with yourself.

***Regarding the plan:***

You need to know what are the courses that you have to follow. From A to Z. The resources are countless on the MOOCS (MIT, HARVARD, YOUTUBE...). However, knowing what to study is key for success.

***Regarding honesty:***

When you understand something, you need to find a way to test your understanding similar to the exams at school. You can't just claim that you have learned it by yourself, if you can't test yourself in regards to the course/chapter.

***Suggestions***

If you are a visual person, watch the courses on MIT website. Else, buy or download books from the internet and start learning them from page 1 to the end.

***Motivation***

I wanted to point out, that in the past, people used to be multidisciplinary, they used to be philosophers, mathematicians, physicians etc... Therefore, if they were able to do it without electricity/internet/community help ... You, I and everyone can do it with all the resources we have in hand. Stay consistent!

Good luck!